# how to disable mobile key pad using j2me(midp2.0)

Tags: java-me

How can I disable the keypad at some stage in j2me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Nokia device and Netbeans as your IDE, then you can take the following steps to solve your problem:

1. Go to default configuration of Netbeans from toolbar
2. Select Application Descriptor
3. Select Attribute tab
4. Select Add button
5. A dialog box will appear.  Fill in the following values.

   - `name:`  **Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad**
   - `value:` **no**
   - `placement:` **JAD and Manifest file**
6. Press OK
7. Build and take .jar file in your mobile and it will hide your keypad.

Comment: Thanks a lot.,but i want generic code for any mobiles(minimum 2 or 3 models)...How i do it...Please guide me...